# Writing non-matching data in Col3 from Text in Col1 and Col2

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sets of data, one is a list of part numbers with revision (**some with no revision**) and a list of the same parts sans revision. These have been manually entered by administrators over years and now I need to create a set of data that is Part Number, Revision.

Due to whatever insanity occurred in times gone past, the revision can appear at random points in the part number, I get a chill every time I say that!

So I need to compare string 1 to string 2 one letter at a time, populating a temporary string with the differences. String 1 will be with revision, string 2 will be without, and due to human error it's likely that String 2 may have more than just the revision omitted, so will need to show those for manual checking.

I found something that's close, but my understanding of VBA is not sufficient to allow me to progress.

```
Function WORDDIF(rngA As Range, rngB As Range) As String

Dim WordsA As Variant, WordsB As Variant
Dim ndxA As Long, ndxB As Long, strTemp As String

WordsA = Split(rngA.Text, " ")
WordsB = Split(rngB.Text, " ")

For ndxB = LBound(WordsB) To UBound(WordsB)
    For ndxA = LBound(WordsA) To UBound(WordsA)
        If StrComp(WordsA(ndxA), WordsB(ndxB), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            WordsA(ndxA) = vbNullString
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ndxA
Next ndxB

For ndxA = LBound(WordsA) To UBound(WordsA)
    If WordsA(ndxA) <> vbNullString Then strTemp = strTemp & WordsA(ndxA) & " "
Next ndxA

WORDDIF = Trim(strTemp)

End Function
```

I would hope to see each letter in the strings compared, once a mismatch is found in string 2, the revision string is populated with that mismatch. The compare would continue to on the same letter on string 1 until a match is found in string 2. For example:

```
String 1 = 123-2A3-456
String 2 = 123-23-456
Revision = A

String 1 = 123-2A3-456
String 2 = 123-23-46
Revision = A5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Something Like this ?**

```
Function WORDDIF(rngA As Range, rngB As Range) As String

Dim WordsA As Variant, WordsB As Variant
Dim ndxA As Long, ndxB As Long, strTemp As String

Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer

a = Len(rngA.Text)
b = 1
txt = ""

For i = 1 To a

    If Mid(rngA.Text, i, 1) = Mid(rngB.Text, b, 1) Then
        b = b + 1
    Else
        txt = txt & Mid(rngA.Text, i, 1)
    End If

Next


WORDDIF = txt

End Function
```

---

**Demo:**

[image]

**Note:** It will only compare 1st string to Second, No Vice Versa. If that's the requirement you can manipulate the current code accordingly.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. Seems so simple looking at it now.